# Allow registered user to register new users and disable auto-login after registration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created an admin panel for my application. Also implemented auth system. But laravel's standard auth system doesn't allow registered users create new ones and always redirect to `/home` route. I have overrided the `register(Request $request)` method in order to disable auto-login, but I still have a trouble with the registration. How can I implement such a functionality? What's the workaround?

**Here's the overrided `register(Request $request)` method in `RegisterController`:**

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    return redirect()->route('users');
}
```

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Registered user cannot register new ones. Redirect to "/home" always happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can manually create a user:**

Just create a new form and pass the required fields and then in your controller use them to create a new user.

```
$user = new App\User();
$user->password = Hash::make('the-password-of-choice');
$user->email = 'the-email@example.com';
$user->save();
```

Comment: How do you think is it okay if I override the `register()` method and implement my own functionality?

Comment: @КамиловТимур If you needed any of the already existing functionality of the Auth's `register()` method then maybe you could override them but seeing as you only just want to create a new User and not have any redirection It's best not to touch the register method

Comment: I have created a method `create()` in a `UserController`, so It worked. Thank u)

Comment: @КамиловТимур Happy coding!!, and please accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I modified the file:

```
\app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php
```

Commenting the redirect within the handle function:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
      //  return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

So far so good.